# Is it possible to extend the KeyboardView for Android's default keyboard instead of copying?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, custom-keyboard

Is it possible to just extend Android's default `KeyboardView`. I am trying to just copy the existing Keyboard and maybe add a few new accessory views to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Android's default KeyboardView". Most devices ship with a custom input method editor.

You are certainly welcome to rummage through [the Android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/), or [search the code on GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Aandroid%20keyboardview&type=Code), and find some `KeyboardView` uses from the Android Open Source Project. Then, you can copy and reuse that code, in accordance with its license terms. However, what you wind up with will not match the device's native input method editor, if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes this is the answer I was looking for, so how would I go about matching each device's native input method editor?

Comment: @AndyRoid: "how would I go about matching each device's native input method editor?" -- rummage through your sofa cushions and cobble together many millions of dollars. Then contact each of the Android device manufacturers that you are interested in and attempt to license their input method editors. There may be several input method editors per manufacturer (I would expect Samsung alone has 20+).

Comment: Ahahahaha okay I see your point, so it's best to just guess a "best" default keyboard then

Comment: @AndyRoid: AFAIK, those who create IME design their own. The ones from the Android Open Source Project will be used directly on some devices (possibly the Nexus series, probably some lower-end devices where they didn't bother creating their own). That, and the fact that you can actually get the source code, is your best approximation of a default keyboard. I'm fairly certain there are other open source IMEs too, that you could look into.